# Determine inner products

Tags: linear-algebra

If I have two inner products $$(i) \langle p,q\rangle=p(2)q(2)$$ and $$(ii) \langle p,q\rangle=p(0)q(0)+p(1)q(1)+p(2)q(2)$$ and want to determine $$\langle t+1,t^2+t\rangle$$ for these two inner products, how should i proceed then?

I'm a little confused as this is all the information I have and have not encountered such an example before.

What I have tried: $$(i) \langle t+1,t^2+t\rangle=((t+1)(2))((t^2+t)(2))=(2t+2)(2t^2+2t)=4t^3+6t^2+2t.$$

Comment: I don't think this question deserve closure. The question is simple but well and honestly posed. I've just made a rollback to the version with the work made by the poster and cancelled by another editing. [comment edited for some typos]

Comment: @user: I agree with you, but the close-voters probably didn't know. This is the first time I see *another user* vandalizing to *remove context*... Crazy. Reopened.

Comment: @user21820 Thanks for your feedback on that. Indeed it is really a strange case and for that reason I’ve submitted to the community to review the first evaluation. Regards

Answer (score 1):

We are dealing with the [inner product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space#Definition) for the vector space of polynomials for the special case:

- $p(t)=t+1$
- $q(t)=t^2+t$

and, by the definition, for the first one we have:

$(i)\;\quad \langle p(t),q(t) \rangle =p(2)\cdot q(2)=(2+1)\cdot(4+2)=3\cdot 6=18$

and for the second one:

$(ii) \quad\langle p(t),q(t)\rangle =p(0)\cdot q(0)+p(1)\cdot q(1)+p(2)\cdot q(2)=1 \cdot 0+2\cdot 2+3\cdot 6=22$

As an exercise, you can check that the give definitions for the inner product satisfy the three properties of linearity, conjugate symmetry and positive-definiteness.

Comment: Thank you so much, not as hard as I thought.

Comment: @kabin Yes no hard at all. Maybe it should be better to give evidence for the variable $t$ and use the expression  $<p(t),q(t)>=p(2)q(2)=\cdots$ and so on.

Comment: \langle: $\langle$

Comment: \rangle: $\rangle$

Comment: @amWhy Thanks for the editing. Please read also my comment under the question. I don't think it deserves closure. The OP shown what they tried and the question appears honestly posed, even if it is simple.

Comment: However, your answer is not good (though I didn't downvote). You should make it very clear to the asker that the given question is **bad**, because an expression like "$t+1$" is **NOT** a function. That is where the confusion comes from. So you ought to state the **correct precise** version of the question that you are answering.

Comment: @user21820 Thanks for the comment, I’ll try to improve the answer.